# Custom Class Method in Blueprint

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

That is my first try codding C++ in UE4. So I follow [this tutorial](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Introduction/index.html) I realised all properties but realise class method going with trouble. So even if I add method in public part and add BlueprintCallable parameter and some custom category I still can't see this method in ue4 editor.

```
// AMyActor.h
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "AMyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class STUDY_API AAMyActor : public AActor
{
GENERATED_BODY()


public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AAMyActor();

    // methods
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = Damage)
    void CalculateValues();
};





// AMyActor.cpp
#include "Study.h"
#include "AMyActor.h"

// Sets default values
AAMyActor::AAMyActor()
{
}
void AAMyActor::CalculateValues() {
     // some code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use that actor class in the editor you need to add the BlueprintType keyword to the UCLASS macro:

```
UCLASS(BlueprintType)
class STUDY_API AAMyActor : public AActor
{
GENERATED_BODY()


public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AAMyActor();

    // methods
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = Damage)
    void CalculateValues();
};
```

[See this page](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Blueprints/TechnicalGuide/ExtendingBlueprints/index.html) for more info on exposing functionality to blueprint.